# AngularJS error handler is not working for radio button coupled with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to add a radio button with 2 field

All and number(this is a input field) (pls refer the image attached)
in this i'm trying to add a error handler for input field. i have patter for numbers "/^[0-9]{1,5}$/" (from 1 to 5) and if there is a mismatch in pattern i want to display error.

```
<div id="_work">
   <md-input-container class="md-input-has-value">
      <label>Work is funnnnn</label>
         <md-radio-group layout="row" ng-model="data.group" ng-change='changecolor(data.group)'>
             <md-radio-button value="All Color" class="md-primary"> All </md-radio-button>
             <md-radio-button value="Number" class="md-primary"><LEFT EMPTY></md-radio-button>
         </md-radio-group>
         <md-input-container md-no-float style="float: right; margin: 0px;">
            <input name="num" ng-model="number" placeholder="5" type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,5}$/" class="numberrr" disabled>
            <div ng-messages="num.$error" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="pattern">Looks like it's not a number?</div>
            </div>
         </md-input-container>
   </md-input-container>
</div>
```

[Radio button link (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdVZp.png)

now the issue is i dont know why i'm not able to get the error msg, when i enter words or numbers more than 5 digits. can any pls help where i'm making mistake.

[See this there is no error message displayed (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh4AD.png)

Answer (score 1):

The format of your regular expression is slightly off. When a string is passed to ng-pattern, it is automatically wrapped in ^ and $ (see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)), so you don't need these characters. You also don't need the forward slashes at the beginning and end, but you do need to wrap the regular expression in a string. Finally, if you're trying to match only the numbers 1 through 5, you can simplify your ng-pattern to the following:

```
ng-pattern="'[1-5]'"
```

However, if you want to match any number of digits from 1 to 5, you'll have to use one of the following:

```
// zero or more digits, from 1-5
ng-pattern="'[1-5]*'"

// one or more digits, from 1-5
ng-pattern="'[1-5]+'"
```